# AssemblyBuilder save without timestamp

Tags: c#, clr, cil, portable-executable

I'm writing a compiler that targets CIL (.Net byte code.) Using AssemblyBuilder to generate the executable file

```
var asm = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly...
```

the final step of which is

```
asm.Save("a.exe");
```

I would like to achieve reproducible builds (same source code compiled with same version of the compiler should generate identical executable). This is currently not happening, most obviously because a timestamp has been placed in the executable.

How do I save the executable with the timestamp zeroed out?

Comment: where in the assembly are you seeing the timestamp, out of curiosity?

Comment: @MarcGravell dumpbin /headers, 5B4A3C7D time date stamp Sat Jul 14 19:10:05 2018

Comment: Is this for regulatory reasons (for example, I know Gambling machines need to have verifiable builds). Microsoft has a tool that can be used to verify two EXEs are the same - while ignoring the parts that consistently change. It may take a lot of asking and convincing, but I know that tool existed in the .NET 2.0 days. I'm assuming it still exists.

Comment: @Flydog57 I'm not working in a regulated industry. I just think compilers should have reproducible builds as a core feature.

Comment: You could dig through the reference source, find the origin of the timestamp and then think of a way to avoid it.

Comment: roslyn has this feature, it's called deterministic, and it's mapped to msbuild (http://blog.paranoidcoding.com/2016/04/05/deterministic-builds-in-roslyn.html). So there is probably a way.